# set and show a countdown timer for a form using js and php

Tags: javascript, php

I have an exam form. i want to set and show a countdown timer (for example 60 minutes) as the student open the page. if they post the form after that specific time it wont be acceptable and they lose the exam.

how can i do that? only using js or need using php as well?

i'm a new so need some clear codes!

Thanks

Comment: Javascript can be easily manipulated you need to log Server's time when exam starts and when exam ends so you can be sure that time is correct. The countdown timer will be in javascript but you will always check server time to be sure that only 60 mins passed.

Comment: i found something for u: http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/aBWce/ or http://coursesweb.net/javascript/countdown-timer-starting-time-added-form_s2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a database for this or some kind of server-side check. When the student opens the test for the first time, the time should be stored in a database and the shown time should be calculated. Otherwise refreshing the page would reset the timer. At the end if the time of submitTime-startTime < 60 seconds then he/she made it in time.

This means that you need PHP for example. It should call a method which stores the current time if a field in database if it isn't allready stored and then do the same after submit. If the time of submit is present in the database, you shouldn't allow him/her to do the test again.

JavaScript should only be used for the display of time, not for validity checking alone without any server-side checking.